# What happens when Java Thread.sleep(100) ?Question about recording netty's Write flush() to ChannelHandlerContext

Tags: java, jvm, netty

environment：

```
OS:win10
JDK:1.8
server: jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.1.v20140609 
netty:4.1.18.Final
```

issue:

When I use ChannelHandlerContext in a multithreaded environment.I must sleep 100 milliseconds or more to send the data successfully, Look at the code snippet:

```
class A{
   public boolean sendData(int deviceId, String hexData){
     try {
         if (deviceChannel.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(deviceId))) {
         ChannelHandlerContext ctx = (ChannelHandlerContext)deviceChannel.get(Integer.valueOf(deviceId)); 
         byte[] data = Command.Trans(deviceId, hexData); 
    
         ByteBuf bufAck = ctx.alloc().buffer();
         bufAck.writeBytes(data);
         ctx.write(bufAck);
         ctx.flush();
         return true;
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      return false;
   }
}

**Class B:** I did not sleep in class B, the data did not send successfully
class B{
  
 public void  trans(){
       int iotAddr=123456;
       String hexData="01020000162C";
       A a=new A();
      boolean isTransSuccess=a.sendData(iotAddr, hexData); //return true,The client does not receive the data,Look at the class C.
 }
}


**Class C:**  I sleep for 100 milliseconds before calling the sendData() method and the data is sent successfully
class C{
    public void  trans(){
       int iotAddr=123456;
       String hexData="01020000162C";
       A a= new A();
       try {
        Thread.sleep(100);              // sleep for 100 ms or more
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }     
      boolean isTransSuccess=a.sendData(iotAddr, hexData);  //The client receives the data
   }
}
```

What happens to the JVM when it Thread.sleep(100)?

Comment: You're suppressing an exception.

Comment: can you edit and add your reproducible code?